# Django import export edit queryset before export

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I'm trying to calculate the pending amount via models and export result in the csv. But the csv shows an empty column for amountpending

```
class FinancePendingResource(resources.ModelResource):

    invoiceNumber = Field(attribute='invoiceNumber', column_name='Invoice Number')
    student = Field(attribute='student', column_name='Student')
    Schedule = Field(attribute='Schedule', column_name='Schedule')
    TotalAmount = Field(attribute='TotalAmount', column_name='Total Value(PKR ₨)')
    issueDate = Field(attribute='issueDate', column_name='Issue Date')
    dueDate = Field(attribute='dueDate', column_name='Due Date')
    amountPaid = Field(attribute='amountPaid', column_name='Amount Paid (PKR ₨)')


    class Meta:
        model = FinancePending
        import_id_fields = ('invoiceNumber',)
        fields = ('invoiceNumber', 'student', 'amountPaid', 'issueDate', 'dueDate', 'Schedule', 'TotalAmount',
                  'AmountPending',)
        exclude = ('id',)
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True

        def before_export(self, queryset, *args, **kwargs):
            amount_paid = FinancePending.objects.values_list('amountPaid', flat=True)
            amount_paid = list(amount_paid)
            total_amount = FinancePending.objects.values_list('TotalAmount', flat=True)
            total_amount = list(total_amount)

            # total - paid
            TotalFee = [float(s.replace(',', '')) for s in total_amount]
            AmountPaid = [float(s.replace(',', '')) for s in amount_paid]

            def Diff(li1, li2):
                return (list(set(li1) - set(li2)))

            amount_pending = Diff(TotalFee, AmountPaid)

            finance_pending = FinancePending()
            i = 1
            while i <= len(amount_pending):
                FinancePending.objects.filter(invoiceNumber=i).update(AmountPending=str(amount_pending[i]))
                i = i + 1

            queryset.refresh_from_db()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have the data to compute `amountPending` already in the dataset, perhaps you don't need to read from the DB:  you could calculate the amount by processing the dataset in memory.  This could be done in [`after_export()`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.after_export).  Then you can added the computed column to the dataset.

Perhaps tablib's [dynamic columns](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/#dynamic-columns) can assist in adding the `amountPending` column:

```py
import decimal
import tablib

headers = ('invoiceNumber', 'amountPaid', 'totalAmount')
rows = [
    ('inv100', '100.00', "500.00"),
    ('inv101', '200.00', "250.00")
]

def amount_pending(row):
    return decimal.Decimal(row[2]) - decimal.Decimal(row[1])

data = tablib.Dataset(*rows, headers=headers)
data.append_col(amount_pending, header="amountPending")
print(data)
```

This will produce the following:

```
invoiceNumber|amountPaid|totalAmount|amountPending
-------------|----------|-----------|-------------
inv100       |100.00    |500.00     |400.00       
inv101       |200.00    |250.00     |50.00
```

Comment: I think the dynamic coloumns will do the trick but im not understanding as to how to do it for a bulk.

Comment: Thank you kind sir :)