# django-import-export export with queryset

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm using django-import-export and just try to export data from outside admin page. My query returns correct answer, but I get empty rows in dataset, only header is showing.

It works only without values and annotate. How can I fix this?

resources.py

```
class ReviewResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = staff_review
        fields = ('employee', 'review')
```

views.py

```
review = staff_review.objects.values(
        'employee'
    ).annotate(
        e = Count('employee'),
        review = Concat('review')
    ).filter(
        month = month(),
        id__in = Subquery(id.values('last_id')), 
    ).order_by(
        'employee'
    )

review_resource = ReviewResource()
dataset = review_resource.export(review)

print(dataset)
```

Comment: Can you add the `id` query, the `month` function and your model to your question? Does your `review` queryset actually return results?

Comment: I found this and working fine! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62328770/django-import-export-edit-queryset-before-export